# how to store values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

In the following code I am getting the scanned value of a barcode.

```
var scanCode = function () {
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
    alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text + ". Format: " + result.format + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    localStorage.setItem("myvalue1", result.text);
    window.location.href = 'page5.html';
    var barcodeVal = localStorage.getItem("myvalue1");
    var test2 = localStorage.getItem("code");
    code = JSON.parse(test2);
    var k = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
    document.getElementById(code[k]).innerHTML = barcodeVal;
    alert(code[k]);
    alert(k);
    k++;
    localStorage["counter"] = k;
    localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));
}, function (error) {
    alert("Scan failed: " + error);
});
```

`myvalue1` is the value i am getting from scanning . I have defined an array and a counter in another js file as

```
localStorage["counter"]=0;
var code = {};
localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));
```

Now i am trying to store the id in the array `code[]` and i am trying to print it in `page5.html`. Above `<script>` is also defined in the same `page5.html`. Also i am calling the scan function again and again to get multiple barcode scanned. I am printing the value in the html as

```
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="code[0]"></td>
</tr>
```

I am getting the error as `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` . What should i do next? Please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BygmL/) when you do the code[k] in the instruction

```
document.getElementById(code[k]).innerHTML = barcodeVal;
```

code is not understood as an array of strings but as a string, so poining at code[0] it does not point to your id but to the bracket.

Do a [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on your code as in the updated JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BygmL/1)

Comment: As i have to save say `n` number of barcodes in the array. So if i call the array `var code = [];` like this and in case of declaring `id` in html like `id = "test[0]"` and likewise . Is such declaration correct?

Comment: Your method of declaring the array as `var code = ["Test", "Test2"];` is valid for limited set of entries but if i have about 15-20 then what should i do?

Comment: Javascript arrays accept any number of entry and of mixed types. Define it empty and add them later. You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/BygmL/2/

Comment: I declared the way you have told me but still I am getting the error.

Comment: i have first declared localStorage["counter"]=0;
               var code = ["Test", "Test2","Test3"];
              localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));

Comment: Raunak, if you want a debug of your code, please create a jsFiddle that can be used by the community as a basis.

Comment: and then i have declared var test2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("code"));
        
      var k = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
     
     
    
       document.getElementById(test2[k]).innerHTML = barcodeVal;

Comment: but still I am getting the same error as  Cannot set property of innerHTML

Comment: Does you HTML page have something with id="Test"? Change "Test" to the id of the element of YOUR page

Comment: Yeah i have declared `id="Test"` and likewise. But still its showing the error.

Comment: Raunak, if you want a debug of your code, please create a jsFiddle that can be used by the community as a basis.

Comment: Its working in the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BygmL/8/ but i dont know why am i getting the error in eclipse as Cannot set property innerHTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56420/discussion-between-mauro-and-raunak).

Comment: I tired that as well but its not working. what should i do next

Comment: Can you see this question? This is the issue I am facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486207/barcodescanner2-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null  plz.

Comment: If you replaces code[k] with the id and still getting the error MEANS that the error is NOT on your Javascript but on 1) the html which is missing the DOM element with desired id or 2) you are firing the event (in other words you execute the script) when the element is not ready in the DOM.