# BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cordova, local-storage

I am trying to develop a barcode scanning app using phonegap-1.4.1 in android. I am trying to store all the values in an array `code[]` and later on I am displaying the values using the array. I am creating a `local storage` of the values. Here is my declaration of an array and a counter.

```
localStorage["counter"]=0;
 var code = ["Test1", "Test2","Test3", "Test4"];
 localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));
```

Here is my javascript file for scanning the barcode and I am using an recursive function in this so that the app scanning continues and the values are stored in the array.

```
 var scanCode = function () {
      window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
      if(result.cancelled == true ) {
          window.location.href = 'page5.html';
       } else {
       var test2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("code"));
        var k = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
        document.getElementById(test2[k]).innerHTML = "result.text";
         k++;
           localStorage["counter"] = k;
          alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text + ". Format: " + result.format + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
          scanCode();}

          }, function (error) {
              alert("Scan failed: " + error);
              window.location.href = 'page5.html';
          });
  }
```

And after storing the values I am displaying the values in some page5.html as

```
                  <tr>
                    <td >1</td>
                    <td>
                      <p id="Test1"></p></td>
                </tr>
```

But I am getting the error as `BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. Somebody please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below javascript Function in your html file ( top of the page).

```
function SaveDataToLocalStorage(barcodeValue)
{

    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];
    var newItem = {
        'barcode': barcodeValue
    };
    oldItems.push(newItem);
    localStorage.setItem('barcodes', JSON.stringify(oldItems));

}
```

Now Change Your barcode Scan Code as below :

```
var scanCode = function () {
      window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
         if(result.cancelled == true ) {
           window.location.href = 'page5.html';
         } else {
           // below function save your data in localstorage.
           SaveDataToLocalStorage(result.text);
           scanCode();
         }

     }, function (error) {
            alert("Scan failed: " + error);
           window.location.href = 'page5.html';
    });
  }
```

Now, if you want to display all barcodes in page5.html just read all barcodes from localstorage and display it in page.

use following function page5.html to display all barcodes in page5.html

```
function displayValues()
{
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];

    for(var i=oldItems.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        var html=document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML=html+"<br>"+oldItems[i].barcode;      
    }    
}
```

make one div name **allCodes** in page5.html

Your page5.html

```
<body>
<div id="allCodes">

</div>

</body>
<script>
function displayValues()
{
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];

    for(var i=oldItems.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        var html=document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML=html+"<br>"+oldItems[i].barcode;      
    }    
    }
displayValues();
</script>
```

//Display in table :

```
function displayValues()
{
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];

    if(oldItems.length>0)
    {
        document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML="<table border='2'>";
    }
    for(var i=oldItems.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        var html=document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML;
        html=html+"<tr><td>"+oldItems[i].barcode+"</td></tr>";
        document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML=html;   
    }    
    if(oldItems.length>0)
    {
        var old=document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML=old+"</table>"

    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56648/discussion-between-butani-vijay-and-raunak).

Answer (score 1):

The error is clearly related to `document.getElementById(test2[k])` returning no element, hence, there is no element with the id given. In your sample this would be `Test1`.

Set the id of the paragraph to `Test1` instead of `Text` and it find the element.

Comment: I am sorry. It was just a typing error while writing over here. I apologize for the error.

Comment: There is still a difference in `Test1` and `Text1`. (`s` vs `x`)

Comment: But still the element doesn't exist. What is the value of `test2[k]`?

Comment: Its an array similar to code[], I am storing the value of corresponding barcode in test2[k].

Comment: Yes, but something is wrong, so can you give the actual value at that time?

Comment: yeah i tried it before `document.getElementById(test2[k]).innerHTML = "result.text";` it shows up as `Test1` but after this app stops and i have error `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BygmL/9/ here is the jsfiddle. Its working fine . I dont know why its showing error in my app. I have all 3 codes mentioned in above question in 3 different html, is that the problem?

Comment: Then there must be a typo or bug somewhere... Can you `alert(test2[k])` before the `getElementById`? How many times does it pop.

Comment: I tried that. Its pops only once with value `Test1` and after that app stops to work. And the error of `innerHTML of null`

Comment: I am not sure whether the elements are already loaded when this function is called. Where is this script located and called?

Comment: Like the declaration of the counter and array code is done in page2.html,then the scanning code and  storing of value in the array is done in page3.html and the printing or displaying of the values are done in page5.html

Comment: I just tried `alert(result.text);` its giving correct value of the barcode scanned.

Comment: But when is `scanCode` called? On startup?

Comment: scanCode is called in the page3.html where `scanCode ` function is defined in a recursive manner.

Comment: I guess the DOM isn't loaded then yet. Try to wrap your first call of `scanCode` in a `script` tag at the end of the html document (after all html body code).

Comment: Which is called on startup I think. Then wrap the call in a `$(document).ready` if you are using jQuery.

Comment: All the js code is written at the end after the html body code. Thats not solving the issue.

Comment: @vijay. NO its in the page3.html where the `scanCode()` fucntion is called

Comment: @PatrickHofman I m not using jQuery anywhere in page2,page3,page5.html

Comment: @PatrickHofman can you suggest some more things which can cause such an error?

Comment: I am sorry, not if the code provided doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PatrickHofman can you suggest me some function in jQuery which will work like `document.getElementById(test2[k]).innerHTML = "result.text";`

Comment: $("#"+test2[k]).html(result.text)